# Python - Running linux subprocess command from script fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to create/run a python program that uses subprocess to call an application is written in C in Python 3.8

The C application runs fine from the command line.
When I run this python file from the command line, it also runs fine, both subprocess calls are made.
When I add the python file to a startup.sh file, then it fails to start the process.

Here is the code:

```
def start_getPID():
    
    #sp.call('app start watchpy', shell=True)
    subprocess.run('app start watchpy', shell=True)
    logging.info('Starting watchpy')
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
      getPID = int(subprocess.run(["pidof", "-s", "watchpy"], capture_output=True).stdout)
      logging.info(f'watchpy PID: {getPID}')
    except:
      logging.warning('An exception occurred')
      time.sleep(5)
      start_getPID()
```

So the command line program I am calling is 'app start watchpy' which like I mentioned runs fine from the command line AND runs fine if I run this file using 'python3 filename' from the command line. The first command will start the process, and the second command gives me the PID so I know it is running.

When I add it to my startup.sh file to start on boot, I just keep getting 'an exception occurred' and when I check the app status it is NOT running, so 'app start watchpy' is not being called correctly.

I tried removing shell = True and that just throws a python error.

Here is my log file:

2024-02-15 14:04:16,114 - INFO - Starting watchpy
2024-02-15 14:04:21,196 - WARNING - An exception occurred
2024-02-15 14:04:26,227 - INFO - Starting watchpy
2024-02-15 14:04:31,312 - WARNING - An exception occurred
2024-02-15 14:04:36,342 - INFO - Starting watchpy
2024-02-15 14:04:41,415 - WARNING - An exception occurred
2024-02-15 14:04:46,445 - INFO - Starting watchpy
2024-02-15 14:04:51,522 - WARNING - An exception occurred
2024-02-15 14:04:56,553 - INFO - Starting watchpy
2024-02-15 14:05:01,629 - WARNING - An exception occurred

When I read about subprocess.run this is what I found:

> Using subprocess.run()
> The run function of the subprocess module in Python is a great way to run **commands in the background** without worrying about opening a new terminal or running the command manually. This function is also great for automating tasks or running commands you don't want to run manually.

So is there a different subprocess call I am supposed to make when calling in the background?  I have tried suprocess.call and subprocess.run and they both don't work / same result.

Thanks...

UPDATE:

I modified the Try / Except to catch the error and it basically says that it can't turn a string to an int, but the string is "", because there is no PID generated. So basically this error stems from the app not starting.

I added a Try / Except block to the subprocess.run('app start watchpy', shell=True) section and it does not do anything.   Nothing is reported and the process does not start.

Also, someone asked what is returned when run from the script or command line, and the answer is Nothing is returned unless you try to start it after it is running. Then you get app pywatch was already started.

I tried this:
**Use subprocess.check_call(('app', 'start', watchpy')) to make it fail if that command fails.**
It works fine if the script is run from the command line, but does not work when called from the startup.sh script

I only have a root user and have run 'app start watchpy' from my home directory and from the base directory on the command line and it runs fine and starts on the first try every time.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE 2:

This **does not** work from the command line, and does not work when the script is called in startup.sh

```
subprocess.Popen(['app', 'start', 'watchpy'])
```

This is the error thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/root/myapp/aioschedule.py", line 51, in start_getPID
    subprocess.Popen(['app', 'start', 'watchpy'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app'
2024-02-16 09:01:57,819 - WARNING - 1st exception occurred
```

UPDATE 3:

```
subprocess.Popen(['app start watchpy'], shell=True)
```

Works when script is called from command line, but not when in start.sh, but does NOT throw an exception.

SOLUTION:

Ended up being a PATH issue to app:

subprocess.call(["/mnt/legato/system/bin/app", "start","watchpy"])

I tried a few different versions of the call command and they work fine once the path issue was fixed.

Comment: When you're debugging, don't use `try/except`. Let the error happen so you can see the full traceback.

Comment: Or at least print the exception so you can see why it failed.

Comment: Don't use recursion as a replacement for iteration. You'll hit the recursion limit after 1,000 tries.

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_call(('app', 'start', watchpy'))` to make it fail if that command fails.

Comment: What is the output (stdout and stderr) of `app start watchpy` when run from your Python program? What is the output when you run it from the prompt? Please add these to your question.

Comment: Likely reasons for `app start watchpy` not working at startup are that the current directory (change it explicitly with `os.chdir('/...')`), the environment (`os.environ`, especially `os.environ['PATH']`) or the user (UID) is different. What evidence do you have that these are the same at startup and in the interactive shell? If you have no evidence, you may want to ask a question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ on getting these values and starting a process with these values explicitly set.

Comment: When I want to see the effect of the environment and the current directory on my program, then I start my program not as `MYPROG MYARG1 MYARG2`, but as `(cd / && env -i MYPROG MYARG1 MYARG2)`, and when it fails, I change the argument of `cd` and add environment variables (from the output of `env | sort`), like this: `(cd /home/user/project1 && env -i PATH=... ANSWER=42 ./MYPROG MYARG1 MYARG2)`. As soon as it starts working, I get a reproducible invocation command, which will likely work at startup as well.

Comment: Updated with new information based on the comments.  Yes, the endless recursion was so I could watch the process, that will go away once I figure on the issue.

Comment: Not a solution to your question, but you [want to avoid `shell=True` in subprocess invocations when you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) but then you need to pass a tokenized list as the first argument.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen` to run a process in parallel with your Python program. `subprocess.run` runs a process and waits for it to finish. (Of course if you use bare `Popen` you also need to understand how to handle and manage the resulting subprocess object. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Comment: Updated with new information